# Ошибка передачи параметров в PDO execute

Tags: php, pdo

```
$SqlCategory = 'SELECT rid.id,rid.date,rid.user,rid.razdel,rid.v_1,rid.v_2,rid.v_3,rid.title,rid.opis,cid.namec,cid.act,uid.nameu 
                FROM rid,cid,uid 
                WHERE rid.user=uid.id 
                      AND rid.razdel=cid.id 
                      AND rid.v_2=0 
                      AND razdel = :cid 
                ORDER BY rid.date DESC 
                LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset';
```

Дырки есть, менял по другому, ставил вопросительные знаки.

```
$Query = $connect->prepare($SqlCategory);
$array = [
    'cid' => $this->get[1],
    'limit' => $Pag['limit'],
    'offset' => $Pag['offset']
    ];
$Query->execute($array);
```

В общем, на примере выше три параметра, параметры успешно передаются в массив, но `execute` выдает `false`, если за комментировать два любых параметра и убрать две дырки, работать будет.

ВСЕ ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ подставляются хорошо.
Ключи менял, не помогает.

Comment: 6 часов проверял код.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''15' OFFSET '0'' at line 1

Comment: судя по приведенной же вами ошибке, подставляются строки в кавычках, хотя limit/offset явно ожидают целых чисел

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''15' OFFSET '0'' at line 1

посмотрите внимательно на фрагмент кода, на который указывает ошибка: `15' OFFESET '0`, кавычки тут явно лишние. А появляются они тут, потому что:

> [Массив значений, содержащий столько элементов, сколько параметров заявлено в SQL-запросе. Все значения будут приняты, как имеющие тип `PDO::PARAM_STR`](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php).

Для явного указания типов передаваемых значений используйте [`bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

```
$Query->bindParam('limit', $Pag['limit'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

и аналогичныо для остальных параметров.

Comment: Без bind'a есть решение? Переписывать класс не есть хорошо.

Comment: @Дмитрий вроде нет

Comment: bind не помогает